# Can't make bootstrap carousel cycle

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My carousel was working, but suddenly stopped. I think problem in some included files.

I'm using RubyOnRails with Twitter Bootstrap.

**EDITED**Names of files in my javscript folder:
application, bootstrap-carousel, bootstrap-dropdown, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-transition, jquery-1.7.2, jquery.validate.min

Here is code in my views(**deleted 'jquery.validate.min'**):

```
       <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7.2','application' %>
```

and generated HTML code:(**I THINK PROBLEM IS HERE**)**which cause delete of second line**

```
   <script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/assets/jquery.validate.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is code form my application.js:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
});  
 }
```

Error from Google Chrome console:

```
       Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel'
```

What is strange, it is working in almost empt html page(only with carousel) and it also have this error from console, BUT it is working.

What you can say ?

Comment: You should maybe investigate why your jquery and jquery validate files are loaded twice? Do you reference them in application.js?

Comment: Looks like you're using the asset pipeline, but also manually including files. [How to use the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline).

Comment: I found error. I deleted file from my js folder. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

and deleted jquery-1.7.1.min.js from my js folder.